# What are some heatmap libraries for drawing on maps?

Tags: python, google-maps, pycharm, libraries, bigdata

I am working in pyCharm and I have a large dataset that I want to analyze. I decided the best way to do this is through a geological heatmap showing the US.

I know of folium and plotly but I am wondering if there are any more out there. These two are great but have some pitfalls (ie with folium it's difficult to pass in values and with plotly it isn't a google maps type heatmap).

Gmaps sounds very good but I believe it only works for Jupyter? Please correct me if I am wrong. I would definitely use gmaps if it could be used for pyCharm.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Heatmap overview](https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/)

Comment: Thanks; I was looking for something a little more like this: https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/plugin-gmaps-layer.html

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late to the party, but:

> Gmaps sounds very good but I believe it only works for Jupyter? Please correct me if I am wrong. I would definitely use gmaps if it could be used for pyCharm.

I am the author of [Jupyter-gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps), which is what you're referring to, I believe? If so, it does only work in Jupyter notebooks. It does, however, let you save the map as a PNG or embed it in other HTML documents.

If you want to create heatmaps on top of Google maps from Python scripts, your best best is probably to dynamically generate HTML. For instance, you could start from [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) and replace the hard-coded latitude and longitude values in the `getPoints` function with points that you pass in through a template (either a simple `.format` or something more fancy like a Jinja2 template).